# can i recover the source of my compiled application?

Tags: c#

I just lost my library and i have a lot of lines of unnecesary code once time i decompile it. It's possible recover or understand more or less the code to rewrite completely to the original source?
For example if i check one part of my projects, i can put one example of how will be the original source before try to decompile it:

```
private static bool ByteArrayCompare(byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
        {
            return b1.Length == b2.Length && memcmp(b1, b2, b1.Length) == 0;
        }
```

Once time i decompile it, the code is completely different:

```
private static bool ByteArrayCompare(byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
{
    if (b1.Length == b2.Length)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int num = 719326676;
            goto IL_000d;
            IL_000d:
            uint num2;
            switch ((num2 = (uint)(num ^ 0x6B86E2FE)) % 3u)
            {
            case 0u:
                break;
            case 1u:
                return SMPTR.memcmp(b1, b2, b1.Length) == 0;
            default:
                goto IL_0048;
            }
            continue;
            IL_0039:
            num = ((int)num2 * -1900091540 ^ 0x4DAC5FA);
            goto IL_000d;
        }
    }
    goto IL_0048;
    IL_0048:
    return false;
}
```

Now happen the same with these classes.
Run:

```
public static bool Run()
    {
        header.‫‬‭‪‪​‎⁫‍⁯‬‌‫‎‫‏⁪‫⁯⁭‭⁪‍⁫⁬‪⁮‮‍‌​​‬⁪⁬⁫‌​⁮header.‪‫⁫‏‎⁪⁭‮⁭⁪‬⁪⁮‎‬​‮⁫‮‪⁯‏‭‎‪‮‭​‏⁯‌⁪⁯​‭⁮⁭‫​‭‮(), header.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
        while (true)
        {
            int num = 1039260164;
            goto IL_001b;
            IL_001b:
            uint num2;
            while (true)
            {
                int num3 = default(int);
                switch ((num2 = (uint)(num ^ 0x3472CD9D)) % 8u)
                {
                case 0u:
                    break;
                case 3u:
                    return true;
                case 4u:
                    num = ((int)num2 * -188976845 ^ -260518362);
                    continue;
                case 7u:
                    goto IL_006c;
                case 6u:
                    goto IL_0081;
                case 1u:
                    num3 = 1;
                    num = ((int)num2 * -1593869856 ^ 0x44175289);
                    continue;
                case 2u:
                    num3++;
                    num = 179700154;
                    continue;
                default:
                    return false;
                }
                break;
                IL_0081:
                int num4;
                if (!RunHandler.HandleRun())
                {
                    num = 311890711;
                    num4 = num;
                }
                else
                {
                    num = 483767846;
                    num4 = num;
                }
                continue;
                IL_006c:
                int num5;
                if (num3 > 5)
                {
                    num = 822334488;
                    num5 = num;
                }
                else
                {
                    num = 1601113283;
                    num5 = num;
                }
            }
            continue;
            IL_004e:
            num = ((int)num2 * -75964955 ^ 0x5EDD0E50);
            goto IL_001b;
        }
    }
```

And the second class:

```
private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (header.id != null)
        {
            goto IL_0007;
        }
        goto IL_003e;
        IL_003e:
        header.id = header.​‏‍⁯‍⁭‏‎‪‫⁪‪‬‏⁬‬‫​⁪‫⁫‪⁮⁬‌‌‌‪⁭‭​⁮‫​‮‏‭‫⁬‮(args);
        int num = -782795078;
        goto IL_000c;
        IL_000c:
        uint num2;
        switch ((num2 = (uint)(num ^ -504079301)) % 4u)
        {
        case 0u:
            break;
        case 2u:
            return null;
        case 3u:
            goto IL_003e;
        default:
            return header.⁪‮⁮​‬⁯⁯‭‮⁫⁯‪⁮⁯⁮‬⁮⁮‫‌‌‬‫⁬​⁫⁯‍⁫⁫‍⁪‮‬⁯‬‮‭⁬‪‮(Resources.MyDLL;
        }
        goto IL_0007;
        IL_0007:
        num = -1157763175;
        goto IL_000c;
        IL_002f:
        num = ((int)num2 * -823262644 ^ -680184524);
        goto IL_000c;
    }
```

It's possible to recover the code of the last two classes. why the code compiled add a lot of loops and make very hard to understand what really happen? It's possible to recover it?

Comment: What decompiler are you using? Did you obfuscate the library?

Comment: Definitely looks obfuscated.

Comment: Always, *always* use some kind of source control!

Comment: Yeah i think that too the library is obfuscated. the only way to recover it and i'm not sure if it would be possible is dumping the dll in memory and getting the original source . not sure if will work.

Comment: ... No, that won't work.

Comment: Not an answer, but in my experience, if the piece of code you need to understand is not too big, then it is not too difficult to read obfuscated code. Just simplify it, little by little, starting from most obvious things like goto IL_003e;        IL_003e;